# How to do IP masquerading on MacOS (10.14+)?

Tags: macos, network, pfctl

I am looking for the equivalent Macos command to the linux:

```
sudo iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o en0 -j MASQUERADE
```

I notice there are some very very old solutions using the ancient `ipfw` firewall, but `pfctl` has taken over and it has a completely different command system!

Answer (score 1):

I believe under pf you are required to edit the pf.conf file for NAT. The [OpenBSD PF](https://www.openbsd.org/faq/pf/nat.html#config) page has some more information on the syntax.

[Murus](https://murusfirewall.com/) is a frontend for pf configuration if you're happy using a GUI rather than CLI.

The linux/unix or networking stack exchange sites might be helpful places to ask about pf if the OpenBSD page doesn't cover your question.

Comment: Thanks, but i already know to use pfctl :) The command i'm using is `nat on en0 from utun1:network -> (en0)` but it doesn't appear to work

Comment: Ah, I may have misunderstood your question - I believed you were looking for the syntax for pf. If your pf.conf file is correct and you aren't generating any errors I'd recommend heading over to the networking / unix stack exchange sites. I've added details for a MacOS frontend for pf to my answer if you're happy to use a GUI. If you have any logs or errors being generated I'd recommend adding them to your question, someone with more experience than me may be able to see the issue. Good luck! :)